# Не считывается значение с radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

У меня есть rest контроллер, который принимает json и записывает его в бд. Есть форма, с которой считываются значения после сабмита и отправляются на метод-обработчик контроллера через `ajax`, считывается все, кроме радиокнопки, в чем может быть дело? Не отрпавляется запрос именно с моего ui, я отправлял запросы через `postman` и все прекрасно работает. Значит, ошибка не в беке.
Вот такой скрипт:

```
<script>
$('#form').submit(function () {
                sendAjaxForm();
                $("#reset").click();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
function sendAjaxForm() {
                var DATA = {
                    name: $("#name").val(),
                    description: $("#description").val(),
                    create_date: $("#create_date").val(),
                    place_storage: $("#place_storage").val(),
                    reserved: $("#reserved").val() //МОЖЕТ ТУТ ЧТО-ТО НЕ ТО НАПИСАЛ?
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: LIST_PRODUCTS + "/create",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(DATA),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (response) {
                        table.append(
                            "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + response.id +            "</td>"+
                            "<td>" + response.name +          "</td>"+
                            "<td>" + response.description +   "</td>"+
                            "<td>" + response.create_date +   "</td>"+
                            "<td>" + response.place_storage + "</td>"+
                            "<td>" + response.reserved +      "</td>"+
                            "<td><a href='#deleted' data-id='" + response.id + "' class='delete'>удалить</a></td>" +
                            "<td><a href='#edit' data-id='" + response.id + "' class='js-button-edit'>редактировать</a></td>" +
                            "</tr>");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("Exception in SEND")
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
```

И вот такая форма:

```
<div class="overlay js-overlay-create">
        <div class="popup js-popup-create" >
            <form id="form" action="">
                <%--<div class="main">--%>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label id="forName" for="name">Наименование товара</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Введите имя"><br/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label id="forDescription" for="description">Описание</label>
                        <textarea style="resize: none" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Введите описание"></textarea><br/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label id="forDate" for="create_date">Дата</label>
                        <input type="date" name="create_date" id="create_date" required placeholder="Введите дату"><br/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label id="forPlace_storage" for="place_storage">Номер ячейки</label>
                        <input type="number" name="place_storage" id="place_storage" pattern="[^0\D]\d*" required placeholder="Введите номер ячейки"><br/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                    <label id="forReserved" for="no">Зарезервирован: </label>
                    <input type="radio" name="reserved" id="yes" value="true">Да
                    <input type="radio" name="reserved" id="no" value="false">Нет
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button>
                <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Очистить поля</button>
            </form>
            <div class="close-popup js-close-create"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: должно быть `$("input[name='reserved']").val()`

Comment: @Jigius, написал. До этого постоянно брал `val()` как `false`, а с такой записью берет всегда как `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[name='reserved']:checked").val()
```

Comment: Да, оно. Спасибо. Вроде пробовал так.. Вы когда мне отвечаете, ошибки сами собой уходят:D